# RecyclerView items refreshing while scrolling

Tags: android, postgresql, android-recyclerview

When I scroll down to RecyclerView items refresh.

For example the items has up and down vote and also has total comment and total vote. Every item ask to web service did user vote, how many votes and how many comment. While scrolling items of RecyclerView ask to web service for each item. While scrolling if user vote an item that little bit coming late to RecyclerView also total vote and total comment coming late. This should be annoying for user.

Edit1: RecyclerView ask to web service all the time even already loaded items if you while scroll up and down.

My questions are for client and server side. How can do that more efficient both side? My solutions are work but I wonder there is any solution more efficient for both side. Have you any suggestions?

I wrote web services using golang. I can change whole service if there is a more efficient way. Because this way so many connections on the database. For one user and for one item has 6 connection each web service and database. I am new at web service things and this ways has some leak I guess.

I think I could explain scenario little bit. Auth user share post image and their post shown in RecyclerView. Posts, total vote and total comment shown everybody but just auth user can vote.

This question so general I know but I have to ask somebody and learn the right way.

Android Client Side
RecyclerViewAdapter

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PostHolder holder, final int position) {
    final Post post = posts.get(position);
    holder.setTitle(post.getTitle()); 
    holder.setImage(context, post.getImageUrl());

    //voteSum ask the web services
    holder.setVoteSum(post.getPostId().toString());

    //commentSum ask the web services
    holder.setCommentSum(post.getPostId().toString());

    if (getIsAuth()) {
        // did user vote? ask the web services
        holder.setUpDownVote(post.getPostId());
    }

    holder.imbUpVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // vote and go web service 
        // after call votesum 
        // call againg did user vote? ask the web services
        }

    holder.imbDownVote.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // vote and go web service 
        // after call votesum 
        // call againg did user vote? ask the web services
        }
```

Comment: have a look at endless scrolling - https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView

Comment: Already has endless scrolling. My question is RecyclerView ask to web service while user scrolling down. My English not well I think I can't explain clearly.

Comment: RecyclerView ask to web service all the time even already loaded items if you while scroll up and down. You can see that if you watch your web service.

Comment: Why don't you pre-load all the data from web then set to the adapter of recycleView ?

Comment: you can update the RecyclerView as and when you want if you're using endless scrolling, I would suggest implementing an onItemClickListener interface for your RecyclerView with the View that is being clicked and the position of that view passed into it, so you can update the web service and update locally via setText when they upvote or downvote instantly, because you have the exact position and exact view. A good example is: https://antonioleiva.com/recyclerview-listener/ .

Comment: @tahsin I use retrofit and I load first 10 data from web and adding to list and set to adapter. This is okay. But when scroll down little bit next item ask for total sum, total comment, and did user vote for web service. How can handle this?

Comment: @BradleyWilson thanks for your responding but I don't get it how can help me this approach?

Comment: @susereng I suggest following that tutorial and getting comfortable with how the interface works, you'll know where once you get it, I promise you.